# Possible to compare against named route in filter?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have the following code:

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  include Admin::AuthHelper
  before_filter :authorize
  layout 'admin/application'

  protected
  def authorize
      if controller_name != 'Auth' && action_name != 'login'
        if is_authenticated_admin!
          redirect_to :admin_login, :flash => { warning: t(:unauthorized) }
        end
      end
  end
end
```

Is it possible to replace:

```
if controller_name != 'Auth' && action_name != 'login'
```

with something that simply checks that the route is not the named route :admin_login? I am using Rails 4.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one way you can do this is to disallow the `before_filter` on the `:admin_login` action, like so:

```
before_filter :authorize, :except => [:admin_login]
```

As a result, you can get rid of the first `if` statement, and need not worry about it at all.

Please let me know if I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I miss that on the API docus, d'oh! Thanks so much, its perfect and I have removed even more code!